# Compositing layer styles

Tags: algorithm, photoshop, layer, shadow, composition

I am trying to implement "Inner shadow" style from Adobe Photoshop.

I have 3 RGBA layers: source layer (brown), inner shadow layer (white) and background layer. They can have Photoshop-like blend modes (Normal, Multiply, Color Burn ...) - blending is not associative!

I would like to blend them together like a layer style in Photoshop. When I multiply Shadow alpha by source alpha and blend (shadow Over (source Over background)), I am getting dark contours around the object, where source alpha is between 0 and 1.

Photoshop reference is on the left, my result is on the right.

[image]

The same problem would be with "Color overlay" and many other styles. Do you know how to do that correctly - avoid contours?

Comment: If you have something between the original and alpha, it has to have a color. It should, if possible, match the potential background (behind the alpha), but if that is not known beforehand, you can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this problem in the [specification of PDF format 1.7](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), at page 339.

So, compositing (**shadow** with (**source** with **background**)) is wrong. The right way to do it is:

1. Composite the **source** with **background** into temporary channels **C**, disregarding the **source**’s alpha and using alpha value of 1.0 everywhere.
2. Composite the (uncropped) **shadow** with **C** into **C** in standard way.
3. Compute a weighted average of **C** with the **background** into **background**, using the **source** alpha 
   as the weighting factor.

As you see, shadow was blended both with source and background. Weighted average was the function I was looking for.